# Mysql Match across tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match, tablesorter

Working on a internal search across Multipliable table. 
Unfortunately the tables can not be joined in anyway as they relate to three different areas (staff)(news)(page) there is no common field.

```
MATCH (News.Tilte, News.Content) AGAINST(@search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH (StaffDirectory.Forename, StaffDirectory.Surname, StaffDirectory.Office, StaffDirectory.Position) AGAINST(@search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
MATCH (CMSPages.PageTitle, CMSPages.PageDescription, CMSPages.PageKeywords) AGAINST(@search IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Open to ideas

Comment: There has to be a way to relate the information. Perhaps it's not a common key that all tables have, but relational databases only work if the data relates in some way. Are you trying to join the tables together? If not, simply search each table individually for the items you need.

Comment: There is no related data in any of the tables, Possible temp table to hold results from the each match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got round the problem by creating a set of triggers, every time information  for any of the three tables was create-updated-delete the searchable required information was sorted in a new search table.